# Creating transcripts in java using array

Tags: java, arrays

so im very new to programming so sorry if is an inane question

But i have been given a homework where i have to create a transcript with java using array,
first i have to enter the students name and code, then the peogram should tell me to enter each lesson’s grade individually

And the result should display the student’s name,code and the grades i have entered for each lecture

I know how to enter make the program prompt me with each lecture and grade entry but showing all the grades i have entered next to thier lecture is what im stuck on

I would highly appreciate it if i get an answer.

Thanks

Comment: @MS90, yeah and some students did it right in the class, I actually deleted the whole thing, i just want to know how i can show the values i have entered at the end of all data entries

Comment: Unfortunately, questions requiring tutoring are too broad to answer on Stack Overflow. Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1288408) for some guidance on how to ask homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code, if there is something obscure, ask for clarification.

---

> MainClass.java class

```
public class MainClass {

static boolean flag = true;
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create new student
    Student student = new Student();

    //print out enter name of a student
    System.out.println("Enter name of student: ");
    //read students name from next line
    student.setNameOfStudent(keyboard.nextLine());
    //print out enter code of a student
    System.out.println("Enter code of student: ");
    //read students password from a next line
    student.setPasswordOfStudent(keyboard.nextLine());
    //create a list of lectures to add them to a student
    List<Lecture> lectures = new ArrayList<>();
    //do adding lectures and grades for them while N is not pressed
    do {
        // enter new lecture name
        System.out.println("Add a lecture? Y or N ");
        //take answer for adding a lecture from a next input
        String answerForAddingLecture = keyboard.next();
        //if answer is yes 
        if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answerForAddingLecture)) {
            // print enter a name of a lecture
            System.out.println("Enter a name of a lecture? ");
            //take a lecture name from next input
            String lectureName = keyboard.next();
            // create a lecture
            Lecture lecture = new Lecture();
            // set lecture name from lectureName variable
            lecture.setNameOfLecture(lectureName);
            //create a list of grades
            List<Grade> listOfGrades = new ArrayList<>();
            //do inside brackets while flag is set to true
            do {
                //print Add a grade for this lecture? Y or N
                System.out.println("Add a grade for this lecture? Y or N ");
                //set an answer variable from the next input
                String answer = keyboard.next();
                //if answer is yes
                if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                    //print what grade is it going to be?
                    System.out.println("What grade is it going to be?");
                    //create new grade object
                    Grade grade = new Grade();
                    //set temp variable to next int input 
                    int temp = keyboard.nextInt();
                    //set grade value to the value of temp variable
                    grade.setGrade(temp);
                    // add this grade to a list of grades
                    listOfGrades.add(grade);
                } 
                //if answer is negative
                else if ("N".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                    //set flag to false
                    flag = false;
                }

            } 
            //do above as long as flag is set to true
            while (flag);
            //reset flag to true again for keep adding new lectures
            flag = true;
            //set a list of grades to a lecture grades list
            lecture.setGradesOfLecture(listOfGrades);
            //set a lecture to a list of lectures
            lectures.add(lecture);
            //set a list of lectures to a students lecture list
            student.setLecturesOfStudent(lectures);

        } 
        //if answer is negative
        else if ("N".equalsIgnoreCase(answerForAddingLecture)) {
            flag = false;
        }
    } while (flag);
    //print a student with all lectures and grades
    System.out.println(student.toString());
}
}
```

---

> Student.java class

```
public class Student {

    private String nameOfStudent;
    private String passwordOfStudent;
    private List<Lecture> lecturesOfStudent;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String nameOfStudent, String passwordOfStudent, List<Lecture> lecturesOfStudent) {
        this.nameOfStudent = nameOfStudent;
        this.passwordOfStudent = passwordOfStudent;
        this.lecturesOfStudent = lecturesOfStudent;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nameOfStudent
     */
    public String getNameOfStudent() {
        return nameOfStudent;
    }

    /**
     * @param nameOfStudent the nameOfStudent to set
     */
    public void setNameOfStudent(String nameOfStudent) {
        this.nameOfStudent = nameOfStudent;
    }

    /**
     * @return the passwordOfStudent
     */
    public String getPasswordOfStudent() {
        return passwordOfStudent;
    }

    /**
     * @param passwordOfStudent the passwordOfStudent to set
     */
    public void setPasswordOfStudent(String passwordOfStudent) {
        this.passwordOfStudent = passwordOfStudent;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lecturesOfStudent
     */
    public List<Lecture> getLecturesOfStudent() {
        return lecturesOfStudent;
    }

    /**
     * @param lecturesOfStudent the lecturesOfStudent to set
     */
    public void setLecturesOfStudent(List<Lecture> lecturesOfStudent) {
        this.lecturesOfStudent = lecturesOfStudent;
    }

    public String getLecturesWithGrades() {
        String temp = "\nLectures:";
        for (Lecture l : getLecturesOfStudent()) {
            temp += "\n" + l.getNameOfLecture();
            temp += "\nGrades:\n";
            for (Grade g : l.getGradesOfLecture()) {
                temp += g.getGrade() + " ";
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student: " + getNameOfStudent() + " with a code: " + getPasswordOfStudent() + getLecturesWithGrades();
    }

}
```

---

> Lecture.java class

```
public class Lecture {

private String nameOfLecture;
private List<Grade> gradesOfLecture;

public Lecture() {
}

public Lecture(String nameOfLecture, List<Grade> gradesOfLecture) {
    this.nameOfLecture = nameOfLecture;
    this.gradesOfLecture = gradesOfLecture;
}

public String getNameOfLecture() {
    return nameOfLecture;
}

public List<Grade> getGradesOfLecture() {
    return gradesOfLecture;
}

public void setNameOfLecture(String nameOfLecture) {
    this.nameOfLecture = nameOfLecture;
}

public void setGradesOfLecture(List<Grade> gradesOfLecture) {
    this.gradesOfLecture = gradesOfLecture;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getNameOfLecture() + " " + getGradesOfLecture();
}

}
```

---

> Grade.java class

```
/**
 * Might add remarks on grades or any other properties some time later, therefore new
 * object is created called Grade.
 * @author 
 */
public class Grade {

    int grade;

    public Grade() {
    }

    public Grade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getGrade() + " ";
    }

}
```